# Revert to Previous Heroku CLI Version from Incompatible Toolbelt Install?

Tags: macos, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

Had an old but functional set of Heroku CLI tools installed on an iMac 4,1 (Intel Core Duo processor) with OSX 10.6.8. 
Upgraded to new Heroku Toolbelt without reported error but lost previous Heroku CLI functionality and getting 'zsh: bad CPU type in executable: heroku' error.
Suspect Toolbelt installed a 64-bit executable in my 32-bit environment.

How / where can I obtain a version that works in my environment short of building my own?

Answer (score 0):

Installing the Heroku CLI tarball http://assets.heroku.com/heroku-client/heroku-client.tgz  addressed this issue.